# Category Products not visible in magento 2

Tags: magento2, products

In my **Magento 2** website, no products are displaying on **category pages**. I did reindexing and flushed cache but issue is not resolved. I have checked magento admin, all products are there with associated categories and all categories has products. Please provide me solution

Comment: Check your error logs @Ash1234

Comment: Check your category and products are assigned to your specific store view

Comment: Have you check consol and error log file?

Comment: Have you checked all your products are set to be in stock and have a valid qty also check the date avaible is not set or is set to a prior date finally what version of magento 2 is it